# How to make two local minikube clusters communicate with each other?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have two minikube clusters(two separate profiles) running locally call it minikube cluster A and minikube Cluster B. Each of these cluster also have an ingress and a dns associated with it locally. The dns are hello.dnsa and hello.dnsb . I am able to do ping on both of them and nslookup just like this https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/ingress-dns/#testing

I want pod A in cluster A to be able to communicate with pod B in cluster B. How can I do that? I logged into pod A cluster A and I did telnet hello.dnsb 80 and it doesn't get connected because I suspect there is no route. similarly I logged into pod B of cluster B and did telnet hello.dnsb 80 and it doesnt get connected. However If I do telnet hello.dnsb 80 or telnet hello.dnsb 80 from my host machine, telnet works!

Any simple way to solve this problem for now? I am ok with any solution like even adding routes manually using `ip route add` if needed

Answer (score 0):

Skupper is a plugin available for performing these actions. It is a service interconnect that facilitates secured communication between the clusters, for more information on skupper go through this [documentation](https://skupper.io/index.html).

There are multiple examples in which minikube is integrated with skupper, go through this [configuration documentation](https://skupper.io/start/minikube.html) for more details.